# "Archiving" publish/subscribe message in Redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am using Redis' publish/subscribe feature.  So the server is publishing 10 items then the client gets those 10 items.

Now however, a new client subscribes to the feed.  I would like them to get the previous 10 items as well as any new items.

Does Redis have a way of doing this using the publish and subscribe functionality?  Is a feed history stored anywhere in the database?  Is there an easy way of doing this?  Is the best way to also store the messages in a list and have the client do an `LRANGE my_list 0 10` on the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd keep a separate archive of the data and have events added to both.  New clients can subscribe and queue the real time events, read the archive until it's up to date with the first published event, then catch up with the published events.  That way you shouldn't miss any published events while switching between the archive and real time events.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this during some research. I know it is old but I wanted to add that with the Redis Streams data structure it is not overly complex to implement persistent messaging.

The publisher would publish messages to a Stream and a subscriber would just get the latest message if that is all it cared about. You can also create user groups to limit how many subscribers can get the message and then mark them as acknowledged to avoid duplicate processing. This is good when you want a message to be handled only once and need a way to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a nodejs app for this sort of purpose. In my case, user data was published to the redis server which i wanted to store, I subscribed to the redis channel with a nodejs app and then saved the details to a database, ive played around with mysql and mongo so far, let me know if this is of any interest and ill paste some code, there are some similarities in trying to store a publish history...

Cheers